# Why is the glycosidic bond between sugars always between the anomeric carbon?

Tags: biochemistry

Why can't the hydroxyl group of another carbon condense with another OH of the second sugar (like 2,4 glycosidic bond)

Thanks

Comment: Well, that would be a "usual" ether, not acetal, wouldn't it?

Comment: can it still occur tho?

Comment: If hydroxyl groups condensed each other at ambient conditions, then there wouldn't be stable alcohols at room temperature.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a tail-to-tail connectivity, which has not been observed so far according to this [source](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep25443):

> Structurally, for ranunculins A-D (Fig. 6), their potential 6-hydroxymethyls of 3-deoxyglucosones (3-DG) connected with another 6-hydroxymethyl group of sugars through a 6,6′-ether-bond (tail to tail ether-bond)10,11,12,13,14,15. In nature, such types of connections are unusual, in contrast to the familiar head to head (e.g., trehalose: 1, 1 connected), head to tail (e.g., isomaltose: 1, 6 connected) and head to body (e.g., sucrose: 1, 2 connected) connections. Coyolosa, a so-called 6,6′-ether-connected sugar, was reported to have been isolated from the root of Acrocomia Mexicana in one study16. However, very soon thereafter, this structure was regarded to be an incorrect and controversial based on the originally reported NMR spectroscopic data and activity studies17,18,19. Indeed, it is impossible that the 13C NMR data of C-6 were still at δC 61.1 when the 6,6′-ether-connection was formed. Nevertheless, inspired by the proposed coyolosa, Takahashi et al.17 and Haines, A. H.18,19 developed novel synthesis methods for 6,6′-ether-connected pyranoses. However, to date, no tail to tail connected sugars have been found from natural products, not to mention the participation of γ-amino acid moieties.

There is no specific reason for tail-to-tail linkages not to exist in nature. If there were enzymes to catalyze the reaction, you would find these compounds. They have been made synthetically: https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2004/ob/b407468h#!divAbstract